# How to get the results from Map in postExecute method of AsyncTask ?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

How to get the results from Map in postExecute method of AsyncTask? I am not able to fetch results in results ?

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Map<String,List<CommentModel>> results) {
        super.onPostExecute(results);
        for(int i=0;i<results.size();i++){
            String ar =results.get(i).get(commentModelList);
           // String content = commentModel.getContent();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter = new Expandablelistadapter(getApplicationContext(),parentlist,childlist);
            list.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);



    }
}
```

Comment: Dubplicate of [how to create ExpandableListView with some json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41781482/how-to-create-expandablelistview-with-some-json-data)

Answer (score 0):

`String ar =results.get(i).get(commentModelList);`

should be changed to

`CommentModel ar =results.get(commentModelList).get(i);`

To avoid confusion is the future try to separate each step into a different line:

```
List<CommentModel> resultList = results.get(commentModelList);
CommentModel ar = resultList.get(i);
```

EDIT:
Also, where are you closing your for loop? If I understand what you are trying to do in your code correctly, you want to iterate over the list that you get from your map not iterate over your map to get the list. So it should be more like:

```
List<CommentModel> resultList = results.get(commentModelList);

for(int i=0;i<resultList.size();i++){
    CommentModel ar = resultList.get(i);

    // use 'ar' in the rest of your code
}
```

Comment: @hiteshchauhan edited. if the solution in edit does not work then you have to provide more info about what you are trying to do and more logs

Comment: ---Android Studio is forcing me to Change to CommentModel ar = resultList.get(i);     instead of    String ar = resultList.get(i); is it correct .. ?

Comment: @hiteshchauhan yes i missed that. ar would be a CommentModel

Comment: but still i am not fetching the result

Comment: @hiteshchauhan i cannot provide any more help without more explanation or logs